# Struck on Microsoft Project 2016 Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have developed a Microsoft Project 2016 macro and it is working.
I have one issue when I import the excel after one time because of the excel is running in background.

Normally,

```
Set ObjXL = CreateObject(Excel.Application) Set ObjXL = Nothing
```

When I do the above code the background excel closed.

If the open excel and read the data

```
Set ObjXL = CreateObject(Excel.Application) Set ObjWB = ObjXL.Workbooks.Open("Location of file") read and update Set ObjXL = Nothing
```

When I do the above code the background excel still running in task manager and got error.
I can able to import only once.

Could you please provide me any feedback for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are not closing the workbook(ObjWB) that you are reading from. You should call ObjWB.Close(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close) before setting the application object(ObjXL) to null.